# How to install Entity Framework and SQLite for UWP Windows 10?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp

I have a UWP windows 10 application, and I was wondering how to install Entity Framework or Entity Framework Core with SQLite to store the database in local `App_Data` directory. The NuGet search is a little bit confusing because there are so many versions listed and none seem to be specific to UWP.

Comment: Read through these [official MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases) on using SQLite with UWP. Have a look at the [Getting Started with EF Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

And old post I know but i just spent 2 days trying to get a WinForms app that uses Entity Framework Core 3 with SQLite working and in case it helps somebody:

- The MS documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=visual-studio) claims that to use SQlite you only need to NuGet install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite.
- I found that even though i did that, when trying to use Package Manager Console to create and apply Migrations I repeatedly got the error "Could not load file or assembly 'SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=2.0.2.669, ..." i.e. its looking for SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll
- There is a breaking change in EF Core 3 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#sqlite3): "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite now depends on SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3"
- So the only way i could get it to work was to manually NuGet install "SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite" and then it all worked fine.

Note that all my SQLlite-related code was in a Class Library project that was referenced by the main WinForms UI project. I found that I also had to add that "SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite" package reference **to the WinForms project** before it will work (because the search path for SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll is related to the main executable, not the database sub-project)

Answer (score 0):

NuGet the following Packages for UWP/Windows 10:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

C# Code once NuGet packages installed:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace App1.Database
{
    public class Account
    {
        public int    Id   { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
        public string Pass { get; set; }
    }

    public class App1Db : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
    {
        Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Account> Account;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, this newer MS Doc (10/12/2018) did the trick:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started

- You will have to update Windows 10 to build 16229.
- Visual Studio will have to be updated to 15.7+
- .Net Core has to be at least the 2.1 SDK

Here are some caveats that I ran into:

- I had to update Win10 to build 17763
- My UWP app. **HAD** to Target Build 17763 with Minimum version of Fall Creators Update
- Project References: The Doc made this way to confusing. Simply, your .Net Core EF Migration console project references your .Net Standard EF Models library project and your UWP application project references your .Net Standard EF Models library project.
- Make sure you don't have any SQLite Open Source libraries in any of your projects (SQLitePCLRaw, Microsoft.Data.SQLite.Core, etc. - these tend to confuse Entity Framework)
- One last thing: I downloaded all the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore libraries into my Models library project **AND** System.ComponentModel.Annotations (you will need this to decorate PKs for your schema)